# Annoying Windows Explorer bar present on OEM Preinstalled Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, toolbar

We have recently got some preconfigured ready-to-use computers.

During some checks, I saw a strange bar located between address bar and toolbar in Windows Explorer.

[image]

[image]

I removed all trialware and Google Toolbar as well, but this bar doesn't go away.

What can I do to remove it?

**EDIT:**

My personal computer looks like this:

[image]

Also, cursor changes to [image] when I hover the bar.

**EDIT:**

On another OEM installation, there isn't the bar:

[image]

Comment: If you just need to remove all the Trialware and also this bar, just format your PC/Laptop with a non OEM Windows 7. As you said you got them recently, that would not be a big deal. Also I have never seen that kind of bar ever before. Also Try removing all the extensions/addon from Internet Explorer.

Comment: Format is a solution, but I don't want to do that. I have numerous PC and I don't want to build an image now (maybe later). Also, removing this bar is not absolutely necessary. I'm just curious about its presence.

Comment: This bar you speak of is in every default installation of Windows 7.

Comment: I'm curious... that bar is sitting right where the Menu bar would be if it were displayed.  If you hit **Alt** to display the menu bar, does it go away?  What about if you force the menu to always display by changing the setting in Folder Options -> View tab -> Always Show Menus?

Comment: I will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bar is actually a resize bar. It appears when menu bar is hidden and if *Lock toolbars* option is disabled.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

> During some checks, I saw a strange bar located between address bar
>   and toolbar in Windows Explorer.

There is nothing "strange" about this bar it exists on every Windows 7 machine.  I have looked both at an OEM installation of Windows 7 Enterprise and a custom installation of Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: That bar does not exist on a Windows 7 machine, I have 3 Systems running Windows 7 (1 Laptop (OEM), 1 PC and 1 VM).

Comment: @AkshatMittal - You don't have a search bar?  That is what the arrows are pointing to.  My understanding is you can disable it but its enabled by default.

Comment: No, he is talking about a grey bar between search and Whatever below.

Comment: You mean where "System Properties" is located?

Comment: @Ramhound - I think you have the same problem as I have.

Comment: @Velcro - Its not a problem.  The same "bar" exists in Windows Vista also.  Furthermore its exists on a fresh installation of Windows 7.  It also exists on the Enterprise version of Windows 7 I am using.

Comment: I never saw this bar before this week (and I'm using Windows Vista or 7 since many years). So my question on Super User. -- OR this is a bug in Windows which appears just sometimes.